# como saber si una frase es similar a otra - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber si una frase es similar o igual a otra, por ejemplo quiero que si el usuario dice *la hermandad* y cuando esta se compare con *clan la hermandad* esto sea verdadero o por ejemplo errores ortograficos *los dw nortc* cuando se compare con *los del norte* esto sea verdad.
he intentado separando cada palabra y validando con la frase original con el metodo `.includes()` de Javascript pero no se cuando decir que coincide, por no mencionar que si la frase es demasiado larga tendria problemas de eficiencia.

```
let frase = "clan la hermandad";

let entrada = "la hermandad";

let entradaList = entrada.trim().split(" ")
let frase_list = frase.trim().split(" ")

frase_list.map(palabra =>{
    // console.log(palabra)
    if(entradaList.includes(palabra)){
        console.log(`si esta la palabra "${palabra}" en la frase`)
    }
})
```

Lo que quiero hacer es algo como las busquedas de google o youtube, cuando buscas *"tutoraal de javascrpit"* te sale *hay resultados para tutorial de javascript*

Comment: Goole usa [IA](https://ai.googleblog.com/2013/05/syntactic-ngrams-over-time.html?m=1) para su analizador sintáctico y mucho me temo que es un algoritmo mucho más complejo que un simple `includes()` o manejo de cadenas. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para definir si una frase es similar de otra, depende del porcentaje de similitud, que puedes calcular basada en la distancia de Levenshtein.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Debes definir cuál es el porcentaje de similitud mínimo para que sea verdadero.

**A continuación el código, mas abajo puedes probar.**

```
function similitud(s1, s2) {
  var longer = s1;
  var shorter = s2;
  if (s1.length < s2.length) {
    longer = s2;
    shorter = s1;
  }
  var longerLength = longer.length;
  if (longerLength == 0) {
    return 1.0;
  }
  return (longerLength - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / parseFloat(longerLength);
}
```

Calcular distancia

```
function editDistance(s1, s2) {
  s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
  s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

  var costs = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i <= s1.length; i++) {
    var lastValue = i;
    for (var j = 0; j <= s2.length; j++) {
      if (i == 0)
        costs[j] = j;
      else {
        if (j > 0) {
          var newValue = costs[j - 1];
          if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
            newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue),
              costs[j]) + 1;
          costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
          lastValue = newValue;
        }
      }
    }
    if (i > 0)
      costs[s2.length] = lastValue;
  }
  return costs[s2.length];
}
```

Uso

```
similarity('clan la hermandad','la hermandad')
```

```js
function checkSimilarity(){
  var str1 = document.getElementById("lhsInput").value;
  var str2 = document.getElementById("rhsInput").value;
  var output = similarity(str1, str2);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = Math.round(output * 100) + '%'
}

function similarity(s1, s2) {
      var longer = s1;
      var shorter = s2;
      if (s1.length < s2.length) {
        longer = s2;
        shorter = s1;
      }
      var longerLength = longer.length;
      if (longerLength == 0) {
        return 1.0;
      }
      return (longerLength - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / parseFloat(longerLength);
    }

    function editDistance(s1, s2) {
      s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
      s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

      var costs = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i <= s1.length; i++) {
        var lastValue = i;
        for (var j = 0; j <= s2.length; j++) {
          if (i == 0)
            costs[j] = j;
          else {
            if (j > 0) {
              var newValue = costs[j - 1];
              if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
                newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue),
                  costs[j]) + 1;
              costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
              lastValue = newValue;
            }
          }
        }
        if (i > 0)
          costs[s2.length] = lastValue;
      }
      return costs[s2.length];
    }
```

```html
<div><label for="lhsInput">Frase 1:</label> <input type="text" id="lhsInput"  oninput="checkSimilarity()" /></div>
<div><label for="rhsInput">Frase 2:</label> <input type="text"  id="rhsInput" oninput="checkSimilarity()" /></div>
<div>Match: <span id="output">No Input</span></div>
```